# PHP curl run times

Tags: php, curl, time, execute

I used curl to get a page online, but can't get full content because the page loading a few times .

If I open that page with browser, maybe wait 20 seconds or more ,the full content show.

I tried use params for curl function ,but it's no use.

The code like below:
$curl = curl_i

```
$curl=curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 * 3 );
$result = curl_exec ( $curl );
curl_close ( $curl );
Util::dump ( addcslashes ( $result, '/' ) );
```

How can I do?

Comment: does your code work given another url?

Comment: Do you see any errors, or just a white screen? PHP might be hitting its own time limit.

Comment: I agree, you are likely hitting the max execution time for your server's PHP. The CURL timeout is set right.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with curl at all. If it was reaching the maximum execution time, it would give that message to the browser. The website likely loads the additional content by JavaScript. Try disabling your JS with your browser and going back to the page to see if it matches up with what cURL returns.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies,but First ,I given the url,and it's no problem,then I can get the page,and it's no question.The only reason to wrote the question  is that an image in that page loading a few seconds , but My script run faster than it.So ,only can get a loading.gif.